# Save and access jwt token cookie between browser sessions

Tags: asp.net-core, cookies, jwt, asp.net-core-mvc

I hope I worded the title correctly. I have a .net core 5 MVC website which uses JWT with refresh tokens for authentication. I would like to enable the user to automatically log back into the website using a stored refresh token if they check a "Remember Me". I already have that checkbox set up on the front end. I am using the code:

Note: the claimsIdentity is ClaimsIdentity with authentication type CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme and a list of claims that include both the JWT token and its corresponding refresh token. Currently the jwt token expires after 30 seconds (for testing) and the refresh token after 6 months.

```
var authProperties = new AuthenticationProperties
{
    AllowRefresh = true,
    ExpiresUtc = true,                    
    IsPersistent = true
};

await HttpContext.SignInAsync(
     CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
     new ClaimsPrincipal(claimsIdentity),
     authProperties);
```

According to [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-5.0), this saves a cookie accessible across browser sessions. My question is, how do I access that cookie? This code isn't run until after the controller has contacted the external authentication API and gotten a new token. Is there a way to check for this token before presenting the user with a login page? As is, check on the Login HttpGet function instead of the Login HttpPost function? I can get the token, I can try to refresh the token (assuming it hasn't expired) and bypass the login.

Am I missing something obvious or maybe this is supposed to be done automatically? Still learning, thanks in advance.

Comment: If we forget about the login page, what do you currently do when the JWT expires? Does the browser automatically request a new JWT? Or how do you currently use the refresh token?

Comment: Or is that perhaps what you're asking about? Because "Remember me" and JWT expiration does not really have anything to do with each other. "Remember me" is about "keeping the user logged in" next time they open the browser and visit your webpage again. Not about keeping the current session going.

Comment: Right. Currently the website checks the expiration of the jwt token before calling the api. If it is expired, then the website sends a refresh token request to the authentication server. So I guess the question has less to do with JWT than I thought. My question is about HttpContext.SignInAsync Cookie that is saved when IsPersistent is set to true. How do I access that cookie between brower sessions?